# MongoDB aggregate: searching between two collections (lookup inside match ?)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

```
products
[
  {
   _id: ObjectId("6225b6f55070a31c458ab681"),
   name: "something",
   number: 1234
  }
]

cards 
[
  {
   _id: ObjectId("6225b6f55070a31c458re681"),
   quantity: 2,
   date: ISODate('2019-02-02T12:54:57.937Z'),
   number: 1234
  }
]
```

products are for general info about products,
cards always belong to some product showing change in quantity at some date.
Combining factor between product and card is number. Number on card always matches some product with same number.

What I want to do is select all products which have cards between certain time period.

So I would run this query on products collection, and I want to match on number HOWEVER, I first need to query cards to find cards which are in given date ranges and THEN use numbers from those cards to match in products.

Im new to mongo so I thought maybe I could aggregate and do match, but then how can I but lookup inside match to get appropriate info from cards first?

Comment: You can refer MongoDB aggregation stages `$match` and `$lookup`.  Refer documentation at: [Aggregation Quick Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do lookup inside match because lookup and match are two different pipeline stage. But yes you can use match inside lookup using pipeline like below

```
db.products.aggregate( [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "cards",
           let: { number_data: "$number" },
           pipeline: [ {
              $match: {
                 $expr: { $eq: [ "$number", "$$number_data" ] }
              }
            } ],
           as: "cardsdata"
         }
    }
] )
```

For more info about lookup stage inside aggregation you can check this link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/